# I'm unable to see the workflows in SharePoint Designer 2013?

Tags: 2013, designer

We have created workflows in SharePoint Designer but when I'm trying to open it - no Workflows are shown.

Comment: Do you use the same account from which the workflow was created? i.e. do you have sufficient permission?

Answer (score 1):

There is a SharePoint designer bug which restrict user to see any workflow.To fix this install the SharePoint designer update from December 10, 2013.

[Designer Update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2837633/description-of-the-sharepoint-designer-2013-update-2837633-december-10,-2013)

Comment: it help me alot                                                                                                 Thank You So much its working....

Comment: @user64478 If problem is solved then please mark the answer as accepted answer..